# Message in Visual Studio Code

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

This is something that is annoying me really hard. Every time I put any `( )`, this message appear: `log(... data: any[]): void`

[image: Photo]

Anyone knows how to disable it?? Or where is it coming from??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's useful info - it's telling you the signature of the function, of what arguments it takes and what it returns.

`...data` means that it accepts any number of arguments, and `any` means that the arguments can be of any type.

(In comparison, for example, calling `toFixed` on a number shows you `Number.toFixed(fractionDigits?: number): string` - it takes one argument, which is a number, and returns a string)

Type information like this is incredibly useful - I'd have a harder time programming without it, and I'd suggest learning the syntax and getting used to it. It's quite nice when dealing with a function that you aren't completely familiar with.

But if you want to disable it, you can open VSCode settings, search for `parameterHints`, and turn it off:

[image]